Sight reader or busker?
Having played with many, many musos over the years, it appears that each is way more proficient in either sight reading, or 'playing by ear'. I can count those who are great at both on one hand - a rare breed indeed, in my experience.
What is it that makes someone so much better at one, but so much weaker at the other? I'd like to hear from anyone who considers themselves really good at both, as well as those who consider themselves good at one, to the detriment of the other. Why are you like that?
I fall into the pretty good 'by ear', but mediocre (at best) sight-reading, no matter how hard I try, so find my choices of gigs are limited. Any instrument is ripe for examples - don't think that's the issue, but you may feel there are other reasons.
There should be another tag - 'playing by ear', but can't find it.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It's heartening that this question has attracted >2,000 views, in less than 4 days, so seems to have a lot of interest, compared with the majority of questions here. Perhaps the vtcs will keep off in the interest it has brought to this site?

Most of them were probably curious how sight reading and busking (as in the commonly known meaning of the word) are opposite to each other.

I think, as Divizna speculated, it's simply that musical practice has been heavily "siloed" by genre, and people are used to what they're used to. I think there are more "cross-genre" artists today than ever, enough to disprove your premise, but still most stick to one kind of music, broadly speaking. I went to the Eastman School of Music and rubbed shoulders with world-class classical folks, but it was stunning how many of them you could disable simply by taking away their page of dots. People who were game for deciphering even the most complex and unusual challenges of new ("classical") music who would look at you like you had two heads if you say "Hey, just play whatever, I'm sure it will be fine." At the same time I've been around plenty of world-class artists in non-classical contexts who get inferiority complexes when asked to put a riff down on paper, or who get intimidated by fancy talk like "secondary dominant."
Your question seems to hint at a hypothesis that such strengths are innate and personal, perhaps having to do with "visual learners" vs "aural learners." There probably is something to be explored in this regard, but unfortunately I think it has little to do with it. It would be great if all practices had more opportunity to accommodate personal learning differences, but for the most part I think it's still chalked up to "what they've done more of." I think "aural learners" in the classical field just have to put up with being sub-par sight-readers, and similar for "visual learners" in non-notated fields. No doubt they all make up for it in various ways, like the classical aural learner being better on the second time through than their peers.
But when we encounter a specimen in the wild that is proficient in one and not in the other, I think it's mostly explained by their training and experience. Of course, age and neural plasticity play a role, too. You can "teach an old dog new tricks," but you can't teach them as well or as quickly.
As I hinted at the beginning, though, I think there are more folks who can operate in both modes than you might guess; perhaps you just don't move in the circles that would bump you into them. I like to think I would count as an example. I've been mostly classically trained, but started playing in rock contexts in my teens, and got interested in Celtic and Scandinavian folk musics at the same time. So my "first language" is dots, but if you play me a riff I can learn it, and I'm comfortable jumping in and making up my own part with no paper in front of me. (Mind you, if you want me to nail the riff exactly note-for-note, I might actually jot down dots. And I definitely don't have a mind that remembers the layout of the song; I have to write down "V V C V C bridge C" and even then forget it half the time.) I once had an Irish fiddler tell me after a set, "I can tell you're classically trained... but I like it nonetheless."
There are many artists whose story goes the other direction, like Mark O'Connor, coming out of a tradition that's largely non-notated and into one where they're expected to compose and publish notated music. I feel like you find the most of such people in these "estuary" spaces where notated traditions rub up against non-notated: people like Nina Simone or Duke Ellington, playing instruments in which they could start with classical-oriented lessons, and then moving into improvisatory spaces.

I think it's more than just “what you're used to”; I've been told by classical teachers (and my experience matches) that one tends to come much more naturally than the other.  Yes, you can gain great proficiency in both, but that will generally require much more effort in the less-natural one.  (FWIW, I'm a natural player-by-ear.  Long practice and experience have made me pretty good at sight-reading a single line — whether a choral piece or bass line or whatever — but piano music still needs time and effort.  But I've always been able to play along, recreate what I've heard, and improvise.)

@gidds - So much more effort is expended in piano lessons to teach sight-reading than playing by ear that any "much more effort" on the musician's end was probably already expended in their youth, from my experience. I have a reasonable time sight-reading and playing by ear, but my playing by ear has horrible inaccuracies when it comes to the accompaniment and sometimes the melody, and my sight-reading similarly often ends up with inaccuracies such as no dynamics and slow speed the first time around.

I'm 100% with you on this Andy. And I have enough friends who started their musical career in one camp but moved to the other. Both directions! I have a bit of both - early classical training for 9 years, then 35 years of the opposite, and now the last 6 years or so trying to go back to formal learning - so I spot in others how they have been trained.

What about people who are bad at both? That's my category :-)
Surely this is mainly about styles and their associated notation systems.
If you work with fake books and lead sheets, you need to ad-lib a lot.
If you work with notated scores, it really helps to be a good sight reader.
I imagine if you look for the people who cross over those simple lines of stratification, you will find musicians with more balanced skills. A classical player who trained in figured bass probably has a better sense of improvising. Pop/jazz players who work in big bands, maybe certain session players, must develop good reading skills. I'm amazed when I see pop/jazz drummers sight read drum parts. Adam Neely comes to mind as someone who is really good at both improve and reading.
To the extent that your question hints at some innate ability explanation, there may be something about power of memory that differentiates people. Personally, my music memory is terrible. I just don't remember the pieces I've practiced. When I played pop songs with friends I always used lead sheets. I've resigned myself to work on my reading skills to compensate.

I believe it is a question of education. Classically trained musicians learn to play what's on the page. They don't seem to spend much time improvising and it is the act of improvising that turns you into a good jamming musician. When learning to play classical pieces, you need to play exactly what's on the page and any deviation, at least in the early to mid stages of training, is treated as a mistake. On the other side, to jam you need to allow yourself to make mistakes and even learn to incorporate them into the jam if possible. So we have two very different mentalities.
The most striking example of this I have come across was a friend of mine, a classically trained cellist. We used to have a band and her boyfriend was our base player. Those of us in the band were, at best, average players. We were just having fun, jamming, playing some originals, but nothing technically impressive, really; she—the cellist—could play circles around us both in terms of technical ability with her instrument and in terms of broader musical knowledge and understanding. As far as I was concerned, she was in a whole different league.
One day, we were jamming to a simple 12-bar blues in A minor. That's about as simple as it gets in terms of musical structure, we're talking three chords. I play the guitar, and I was improvising a solo. She came up to me, super impressed, and asked me what I was playing. I had no idea what I was doing other than screwing around with the A minor pentatonic. She proceeded to copy me, which of course she could do perfectly well, on her cello and was also kind enough to tell me what I was doing. But this was not natural to her, and it wasn't easy, and she had to copy me to be able to do it, despite the fact that I am a far, far inferior musician than she is.
She explained to me that in all her years of training, she never got to just let loose and play around with just a scale or two for guidance so it was both hard and unnatural for her. The really interesting bit, for me at least, is that once she realized that all I was doing was playing little riffs on the pentatonic scale, the next time we tried to jam with her, which was maybe a week after this, she had grokked the idea and she could bring all of her formidable technical skill and knowledge to bear and proceeded to lift our jam to a whole new level.
All this to say that, at least for those who aren't so good at playing by ear and jamming to a tune but do have a very strong grounding in music, there seems to be a gate that needs to be opened. They need to realize how to apply all their knowledge in the absence of any written guides, and not all of them can do it. Just like how some people enjoy free form tasks when students ("find a subject and write about it") while others are horrified by that and require a specific target in order to be able to work. However, those people who come with  classical training and then manage to open this door, boy oh boy can they play!

I feel it's the grounding that leaves the most lasting skill. Those who have come through the exam system - mainly classical - will have, as part of their syllabus, needed to gain marks for good sight-reading, but a lot of exams don't (or didn't) include playing by ear. Yes, there were ear tests, but they mostly involved singing and/or clapping - not the same as 'playing by ear'.
'Playing by ear' - it seems so many guitarists manage that extremely well, and never feel the need to read. Maybe it's the instrument, or the kind of music often played on guitar - not including classical, of course - but wouldn't mind betting the percentage of a random group of guitarists who read would be quite low. Giving rise to the old one - how do you make a guitarist play quietly? Put some music in front of him! I know it worked with me...
Unfortunately, none of my teachers on other instruments (particularly piano) managed to help my poor sight-reading, but a quite good ear got me through where that let me down, and still does!
Also, for a lot of us, there's an innate skill of one or the other. If one skill is weak, the other tends to be favoured. Which weakens the weaker one, while strengthening the already stronger one. So the differential grows bigger.
Of course there are players who are great at both, but I bet they have had to work hard on their weaker skill.

I could sight read at 13 years old but couldn't at 17.. It was practiced every day, just like playing by ear which I could do for some stage of my 20's. For me it was from playing guitar in different tunings, I have at least one guitar tuned to each E, Db, and C standard including bass guitars. I would mix songs with tunings and that helped me to pick the notes. Could never get the nuances in some chords unless I had the correct tuning and the artist was familliar.
Now I struggle to read and hear because I never kept up with practice, just prefer to make noise and play my own stuff.
When I wan't to play a cover or join in with others it's not very smooth and in the moment I wish I had kept the skills up, but the feeling doesn't last for long, I'd rather create than copy...
If that's what you want, you gotta do it, there's no secret.

I think it's a matter of which is practiced most. Many of the musicians I have worked with were quite good at both.
